# Getting attributes values and comparing the values from other attributes (values have line break in HTML) UseCase: Price comparison

Tags: karate

I am a big fan of Karate and exploring Karate UI for the end-to-end testing but stuck on one simple thing which is finding element by attribute where value has a line break in HTML and assertion always fails.

When I use
And match attribute('#eg01SubmitId', 'type') == 'submit'
And match text('.myClass') == 'Class Locator Test'

Use case: Comparing Prices (Getting price quotes from elements in one application and comparing it with price quotes in other applications)
[image]

Like Car deals quotes
[image]

[image]

What is the best strategy in this use case and how I can implement this in Karate?

Answer (score 2):

Just call `trim()` on any string to remove leading and trailing white-space.

For example:

```
* def before = '  hello world\n  '
* def after = before.trim()
* match after == 'hello world'
```

Also note that [`waitForText()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#waitfortext) is designed to do a string "contains" match by default.

You can also find-and-replace line feeds. Any thing is possible, you just need to know the Java methods (on String) you can call.

```
* def before = 'hello\nworld'
* def after = before.replace('\n', ' ')
* match after == 'hello world'
```

Comment: Thanks !! It worked ... 


And Can we compare  * def after = before.trim() in another scenario ?
* def beforequoteelead = text("//input[@id='txtVehiclePrice']")
    * def afterquoteelead = beforequoteelead.trim()
    * match afterquoteelead == quotes.after (This is after in another scenario)

Background
* def quotes = read('classpath:com/cdk/reusable_hooks/RoadsterOrderSubmission.feature')

My next question would be Can we have a JS function that will extract all the quote prices and store it and then compare it in a different scenario?